# The union of two ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let two ordered pairs are $(a,b)$ and $(p,q)$.

Then, is $(a,b)\cup(p,q)=(a,b,p,q)$?

Comment: Are you using the definition $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$?

Comment: i am not sure whether such definition need to be considered, since i need to find the solution (a,b)U(p,q)=(a,b,p,q). But, i did not know how can i get the solution

Comment: If you are confused about the definition, then I believe the answer you seek is "no, they are not equal". Maybe some context would be helpful, e.g., is this part of a True/False question series?

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 4):

Union is not defined on ordered pairs. You can define concatenation, which will end up as an ordered quadruplet, but it's not the same as a union.

If you consider ordered pairs as interpreted by sets somehow then the question has a different interpretation. Under the Kuratowski definition ($(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$) the union of two ordered pairs is just a set which two to four elements which doesn't satisfy the definition of an ordered pair anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Asaf, we have a "play" with two things :

**(i)** an *ordered pair* is a set; so "obviously" we can perform the set-union operation on two ordered pairs and obtain a new set. We must use the definition of *ordered pair* that we have at our disposal, I assume it is the following, due to Kuratowski :

> $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$

and "write down" the result.

**(ii)** the second issue is wether the result it is an "interesting" one and, in particular, if it is an *ordered quadruple* (assuming that the formula $(a,b,p,q)$ is a "sloppy" version of it). This must be checked.

You must start with an *ordered triple*, that is :

> $((x,y),z)=\{ \quad \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}, \{ \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}, z \} \quad \}$.

Assuming that I've copied the formula without errors, you must add the last "actor" of the play (i.e. $w$), unwind the formula and see what happens; is the result equal to :

> $(x,y) \cup (z,w)$ ?

The last one has (as we expect) four elements :

> $(a,b) \cup (p,q) = \{ \quad \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{p\}, \{p,q\} \quad \}$.

What is the structure of $(((a,b),p),q)$ ?

If we dig into it a little bit, we have (again, please check the parentheses):

> $\{ \quad \{(a,b), \{(a,b), p \}\}, \{ \{(a,b), \{(a,b), p \}\}, q \} \quad \}$.

First consideration : being an *ordered $n$-uple* a "nested" ordered couple, it has two elements, instead of four.

Second consideration : the "original" objects : $a, b, p, q$, are at different "depth" in the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments, the effect of set operations on ordered pairs is generally not considered and if at all it depends on the way ordered pairs are introduced *as sets*. In everyday usage we use only the fact $$\tag1(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c\land b=d$$ about ordered pairs. To show that such a concept exists to a sceptic who believes in set theory, but not in pairs, we may define $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and verify that $(1)$ holds if we do so. Other definitions than $(1)$ exist and whether or not $(a,b)\cup (c,d)=(a,b,c,d)$ depends on the choice of such a definition.

However, If the equality were true, we'd have
$$(a,b,c,d)=(a,b)\cup(c,d)=(c,d)\cup (a,b)=(c,d,a,b) $$
for all quadruples, contradicting the usual postulate
$$(a,b,c,d)=(e,f,g,h)\iff a=e\land b=f\land c=g\land  d=h.$$